# How to execute notify after Gulp copy task is completed?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a `copy` task in my `gulpfile.js`, and I want notify (`gulp-notify`) after copy is complete, now, when I execute `copy` task, `notify` function is called many times.

```
const notify = require('gulp-notify')
    , gulp = require('gulp')
    ;

gulp.task('copy', copyTask);

function copyTask() {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
        .pipe(notify('Copy task is completed!'));
}
```

In my terminal:

```
[13:23:40] Starting 'copy'...
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
[13:23:40] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copy task is completed.
```

How to can I fix this, to execute only time, after `gulp.dest` is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`onLast` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify#optionsonlast):

```
function copyTask() {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
    .pipe(notify({
      message: 'Copy task is completed!',
      onLast: true
    }));
}
```